# Setting Up Static IP Address With GUI

Tags: port-forwarding

I am new to linux and am trying to set up a static IP address so I can port forward.  I am using version 16.04 and was wondering if there was an easy GUI to access or a step by step by tutorial.

Comment: Yes, there is and is the exact same network manager / network indicator you use for Ethernet or WiFi. Click it > Edit connections and you're there. Select the connection you want and in IPV4 and/or IPV6 change from the default "Automatic (DHCP)" to "Manual" and enter the required static IP. You need also to make a provision for that at the router.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special reason why you want to do this in Ubuntu and not on your router? If you're using a router that you can manage yourself, you should be able to login to its interface via your browser and set a static IP address as well as port-forwards there.

Comment: I do not see an area in my router to assign a static ip address to an device so was trying to assign a static ip address through the ipv4 protocol on Ubuntu and then plug that ip address into the router to forward information to that static ip.